# Converting Angular Material Dialog component to Bottom-sheet in mobile screen using css

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, modal-dialog, bottom-sheet

I am trying to convert a mat-dialog position from `center`(desktop) to `bottom in full width`(mobile).
So it should look likes a dialog in large screens and bottom-sheet in smaller devices. I am able to achieve this using `breakpointObserver`(I will be listening the breakpoint change and update the config properties).

But I would be really happy if someone can help me to achieve the same using css media queries.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is searching solution for similar situation.

Add a custom class to the dialog;

```
this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, { panelClass: 'my-custom-dialog' });
```

Add the following style to the global css:

```
@media (max-width:641px)  {
    .my-custom-dialog {
      width: 100% !important;
      align-self: flex-end !important;
    }
}
```